# AWS Security Group: What is needed in inbound and outbound rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

Both `main_ec2` and `guest_ec2` have their own security groups.

`main_ec2` wants to connect to `guest_ec2` on port 9012.

So I have mention port (9012) destination (`guest_ec2`) rule in outbound rules of `main_ec2`. Should I need to mention the another rule in the inbound of `guest_ec2` to accept the traffic like port (9012) source (`guest_ec2`) rule in the inbound of `guest_ec2`? Or else not required to mention am inbound rule in `guest_ec2`?

Comment: Yes, you need to allow the request on both ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `main_ec2` to be able to access `guest_ec2` on port 9012, then the configuration should be:

Security group on `main_ec2`:

- Permit **Inbound** access as necessary for your application (and presumably SSH)
- Leave the **Outbound** rules as the default "Allow All" rules because you can normally trust your own system

Security group on `guest_ec2`:

- Permit **Inbound** access on port 9012 from the Security Group on `main_ec2` (that is, it should specifically refer to the other Security group)
- Leave the **Outbound** rules as the default "Allow All" rules because you can normally trust your own system